# MSAL authentication with Xamarin and Android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, asp.net-web-api2, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have implemented a way to consume my Web API 2 with Xamarin Forms through MSAL authentication.
It works great on UWP but I can't get to authenticate on the Android platform.

I always get a `Authorization has been denied for this request.`

The code for the authentication looks like this :

```
public static PublicClientApplication IdentityClientApp = null;

internal static void InitializeLogin(PlatformParameters platformParameters)
    {
        App.IdentityClientApp = new PublicClientApplication(Constants.ApplicationID);
            if (platformParameters != null)
                App.IdentityClientApp.PlatformParameters = platformParameters;
```

I get the first token this way:

```
public async Task SignIn()
{
    if (App.IdentityClientApp != null)
        this.authenticationResult = await App.IdentityClientApp.AcquireTokenAsync(new String[] { Constants.ApplicationID });
}
```

And refresh it before every call to my API like that :

```
public async Task<String> RefreshToken()
{
    if (App.IdentityClientApp != null)
    {
        this.authenticationResult = await App.IdentityClientApp.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(new String[] { Constants.ApplicationID });
    }
    return (this.authenticationResult.Token);
}
```

In my Android MainActivity.cs, I call the login initialization method with the platformParameters :

```
App.InitializeLogin(new PlatformParameters(this));
```

Comment: To narrow the issue, please decode the access_token from this site to check whether the `aud` claim matches the **audience** config to protect the web API.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The audience seems to be right because I see my applicationID there.

Answer (score 0):

PlatformParameters is from the first preview of MSAL from 2016. That preview wasn't supported, and the release of the more recent preview (which is supported) supersedes it. Please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-xamarin-native-v2/ for a complete sample showing how to use the latest MSAL on Android.
Also note: issuing an access token for an API other than the Microsoft API from a native client is temporarily not supported by the Azure AD v2 endpoint. It should come online shortly but we have no ETA to share at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I kinda noticed that I couldnt authenticate on my API with the newer versions of MSAL.
Would you know what would be the best way to authenticate on my API and use the Graph API ?

Comment: Do you mean that it is not yet possible to authenticate on an API from Android only or with any of the platforms ?
   I have been able to get an access token on the UWP platform without any issue.

Comment: No access token for any API that is not the MS graph regardless of the client platform as it is a service side behavior. The fix should be few weeks away (tho i can't fully commit on the timing). Again sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: It's fine. I just don't understand how I have been able to make it work on the UWP platform if it is not supposed to.

Comment: Would be interesting to see some code snippet and traces. If you want to follow up you can contact me thru www.cloudidentity.com, the contact form will send me an email and I can reply to that to open a channel :)

Comment: We can make it work using the latest "alpha" MSAL for .net library. This does not work using the latest one (preview).Will our solution fail soon without notice ? Is there any ETA for an MSAL for .net / AAD v2.0 update (a few weeks in august) that will offcially support this scenario, please ?